# How to store elements of a string array into a struct in C?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, struct

So I have a string: `a = 2.b 1.d; milk cheese`

I separate it by removing all the special characters (the equal sign, the period, the semicolon) and this is done using the strtok function in C. I take each element and store it into an array of strings, like this:

```
arr[0]="a"
arr[1]="2"
arr[2]="b"
arr[3]="1"
arr[4]="d"
arr[5]="milk"
arr[6]="cheese"
```

Now, I want to take those values and put them into a struct. Here is my struct:

```
struct stopPoints {
    int  weights[10];
    char connectingPoints[10];
    char *items;
    int startBool;
};
```

I've declared the struct and called it myPoint. Now, I want to store each of the separated elements up top into my struct. For example, i want to store the "2" and "1" into `myPoint.weights[0]` and `myPoint.weights[1]`. I want to store the "a" and "b" into `myPoint.connectingPoints[0]` and `myPoint.connectingPoints[1]`.

I approached this by trying to distinguish between letters and numbers. I loop through the "arr" array and check if each index has either a letter or number. This is done by using the ASCII values (I know there's a better method to doing this according to the answers on my previous post). But when I try printing out the first weight element in my struct, I get a random value. How can I fix this? My code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct stopPoints {
    int  weights[10];
    char connectingPoints[10];
    char *items;
    int startBool;
};

int main ()
{
    struct stopPoints myPoint;
  char *arr[30];
  char str[] ="a = 2.b 1.d; milk cheese";
  char * pch;
  pch = strtok (str," ;=,.-");
  arr[0] = pch;
  int i=0;
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    //printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ;=,.-");
    arr[i+1] = pch;
    printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
    i++;
  }
    int sizeofstring = sizeof(str)/sizeof(str[0]);

    int x,y=0;
     for (x=0; x<sizeofstring; x++){
          if (arr[y+1] >= 97 && arr[y+1] <= 122){
                myPoint.connectingPoints[x] = arr[y+1];
                y++;
          }
          else if (arr[y+1] >= 48 && arr[y+1] <= 57){
                myPoint.weights[x] = arr[y+1];
                y++;
          }
     }

    printf("%d\n", myPoint.weights[1]);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, very good job on the detail, the minimum complete and verifiable example, and the formatting of your question. Next, it is apparent you are quite lost...

It is hard to imagine a more awkward approach to doing what you are attempting to do, but for the sake of learning, there is quite a bit of learning that can be had in doing it in an awkward fashion.

To begin, do not use *magic numbers* in your code. This is for readability and maintainability as your code grows. `10, 30, 97, 122, 48 and 57` are all *magic numbers*.

```
#define CPWT 10     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define NPTR 30     /*   (do not use "magic numbers" in your code)   */
```

Do not use *magic numbers* for characters. While you should use the macros provided in `ctype.h` for `islower()` and `isdigit()`, if you are going to use characters, then use *characters*, e.g. `if (foo >= 'a' && foo <= 'z')` not `97` and `122`. Just single quote the character.

Next, you are overwriting every pointer in `arr` every time you assign `arr[i+1] = pch;` Why?

```
    char *arr[NPTR];                /* array of 30 UNINITIALIZED pointers */
```

While `strtok` does return a pointer, when you assign `arr[i+1] = pch;`, you are assigning the **same pointer** to each pointer in `arr`. When you are done, every element in `arr` will hold the last value returned by `strtok` (and since you assign **after** the last call to `strtok` returns `NULL` -- you most likely SegFault)

Further, before you "store" anything at the address of `arr[0]` to `arr[NPTR-1]`, you must allocate storage based on the length of the string you are storing. (and yes, even though you are only storing a *single-character* in many elements, you are storing *strings* -- and every string requires a *nul-terminating character*).

You cannot assign strings in C (except for the assignment of *string literals* or during initialization of an array). Otherwise, you must **copy** strings in C.

So since you begin with *uninitialized, unallocated* pointers in `arr`, you must *allocate* and then *copy* to store information at each pointer address. You have two ways of doing so, (1) either `malloc (length + 1)` characters, **validate** the allocation, and then `strcpy` (or more efficiently `memcpy` since you have already scanned to find the *nul-character* with `strlen()`), or (2) if you have `strdup()` it will both allocate and copy as you did in (1) in a single function call. (**note:** since `strdup` allocates, you still must **validate** the allocation succeeded)

Example (1)

```
    if ((pch = strtok (str," ;=,.-")) != NULL) {    /* validate each call */
        size_t len = strlen (pch);                  /* get length */
        if ((arr[0] = malloc (len + 1)) == NULL) {  /* allocate/validate */
            perror ("arr[0]-malloc");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        memcpy (arr[0], pch, len+1);    /* copy! string to arr[0] */
        i++;
    }
```

Example 2 (using `strdup` to allocate/copy)

```
    /* only loop if good return from strtok */
    while ((pch  = strtok (NULL, " ;=,.-")) != NULL)
    {
        /* allocate/copy all at once with strdup (if you have it) */
        if ((arr[i] = strdup (pch)) == NULL) {
            perror ("arr[n]-strdup");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Since you have just filled `i` elements of `arr`, there is no need for:

```
    int sizeofstring = sizeof(str)/sizeof(str[0]);
```

You know you have `i` strings in `arr` -- use `i` not `sizeofstring` and step through each string you stored in `arr`, not each character in `str`. That defeats the entire purpose of having *tokenized* `str`. Further, you only want to consider *single character* or *single digit* strings in `arr` (not `"milk"` and `"cheese"`) when setting `connectingPoints` and `weights`, so check whether the 2nd character is the *nul-character*, otherwise skip the element of `arr`.

You can't use `y` for both `connectingPoints` and `weights`, you have `a, b, d` `connectingPoints` (3 of them) and only 2 `weights`. You would be attempting to access outside the valid data in `weights` if you iterated from `j = 0; j < y; ...`

Again, you cannot assign a pointer as a character, so the easiest way to assign the 1st character in a string as a character, is simply to *dereference* the pointer, e.g. `*arr[x]` (which is equivalent to the character `arr[x][0]`). That in mind, you could do:

```
    /* i contains the number of strings in arr - use it */
    for (x = 0; x < i; x++) {
        if (arr[x][1] == 0) {   /* only consider single char strings in arr */
            if (cpts < CPWT && islower(*arr[x])) { /* check bound/lowercase */
                myPoint.connectingPoints[cpts] = *arr[x];  /* assign char */
                cpts++;
            }
            else if (weights < CPWT && isdigit(*arr[x])) { /* same w/digits */
                myPoint.weights[weights] = *arr[x];
                weights++;
            }
        }
    }
```

(**note:** the separate use of the counters `cpts` and `weights` instead of a single `y`)

Putting all the pieces together, you could do the awkward approach with something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define CPWT 10     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define NPTR 30     /*   (do not use "magic numbers" in your code)   */

struct stopPoints {
    int  weights[CPWT];
    char connectingPoints[CPWT];
    char *items;
    int startBool;
};

int main (void)
{
    struct stopPoints myPoint = { .weights = {0} };
    char *arr[NPTR];                /* array of 30 UNINITIALIZED pointers */
    char str[] ="a = 2.b 1.d; milk cheese";
    char *pch;
    int i = 0, x, cpts = 0, weights = 0;

    if ((pch = strtok (str," ;=,.-")) != NULL) {    /* validate each call */
        size_t len = strlen (pch);                  /* get length */
        if ((arr[0] = malloc (len + 1)) == NULL) {  /* allocate/validate */
            perror ("arr[0]-malloc");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        memcpy (arr[0], pch, len+1);    /* copy! string to arr[0] */
        i++;
    }

    /* only loop if good return from strtok */
    while ((pch  = strtok (NULL, " ;=,.-")) != NULL)
    {
        /* allocate/copy all at once with strdup (if you have it) */
        if ((arr[i] = strdup (pch)) == NULL) {
            perror ("arr[n]-strdup");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        i++;
    }

    /* i contains the number of strings in arr - use it */
    for (x = 0; x < i; x++) {
        if (arr[x][1] == 0) {   /* only consider single char strings in arr */
            if (cpts < CPWT && islower(*arr[x])) { /* check bound/lowercase */
                myPoint.connectingPoints[cpts] = *arr[x];  /* assign char */
                cpts++;
            }
            else if (weights < CPWT && isdigit(*arr[x])) { /* same w/digits */
                myPoint.weights[weights] = *arr[x];
                weights++;
            }
        }
    }

    puts ("arr contents:");
    for (x = 0; x < i; x++)
        printf (" arr[%2d]: %s\n", x, arr[x]);

    puts ("\nconnectingPoints:");
    for (x = 0; x < cpts; x++)
        printf (" myPoint.connectionPoints[%2d]: %c\n", 
                x, myPoint.connectingPoints[x]);

    puts ("\nweights:");
    for (x = 0; x < weights; x++)
        printf (" myPoint.weights[%2d]: %c\n", 
                x, myPoint.weights[x]);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** the use of `islower()` and `isdigit()` from `ctype.h`)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/strtokarrptrs
arr contents:
 arr[ 0]: a
 arr[ 1]: 2
 arr[ 2]: b
 arr[ 3]: 1
 arr[ 4]: d
 arr[ 5]: milk
 arr[ 6]: cheese

connectingPoints:
 myPoint.connectionPoints[ 0]: a
 myPoint.connectionPoints[ 1]: b
 myPoint.connectionPoints[ 2]: d

weights:
 myPoint.weights[ 0]: 2
 myPoint.weights[ 1]: 1
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: This is amazing. thanks so much. I actually spent a lot of time looking at my code after posting this and found every single mistake i made, corrected it, added a few more stuff, and was able to successfully fill my entire struct with the contents of my string. I unfortunately didn't see this post until now. I will definitely have more questions in the near future regarding this program.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really understanding what you are trying to do, but `arr` is an array of pointers, `myPoint.connectingPoints` is an array of `char` and `myPoint.weights` is an array of `int`. So `myPoint.connectingPoints[x] = arr[y+1]` and `myPoint.weights[x] = arr[y+1]` will do pointer to `char` or `int` conversion, which is generally a bad idea.

Maybe you wanted to do

```
myPoint.connectingPoints[x] = arr[y+1][0];
```

and

```
myPoint.weights[x] = arr[y+1][0];
```

The same goes for the comparisons with `arr[y+1]`. 97, 122, 48 and 57 are not hardcoded memory addresses, are they?

This is totally ignoring the fact that you have a buffer overflow in `myPoint.connectingPoints` and `myPoint.weights`. Hint: `sizeofstring` is larger than 10.

Please, always compile with `-Wall`. The flag exists for a reason

Answer (score 0):

You do not initialize your struct at any point and you alternate by assigning values
to myPoint.connectionPoints[x] and myPoint.weights[x] but then skip a spot in the other
array so that is the reason you get random values

```
      if (arr[y+1] >= 97 && arr[y+1] <= 122){
            myPoint.connectingPoints[x] = arr[y+1];  // myPoint.weights[x] left unassigned 
            y++;
      }
      else if (arr[y+1] >= 48 && arr[y+1] <= 57){
            myPoint.weights[x] = arr[y+1]; // myPoint.connectingPoints[x] left unassigned
            y++;
      }
```

I would suggest you convert your values to the struct already when you get the
return value from strtok to avoid allocating for things you do not later
need.

E.g.

```
    int index = 0;
    for (char* pch = strtok(str, " ;=,.-"); pch != NULL; pch = strtok(NULL, " ;=,.-")
    {
      switch (index++)
      {
      case 0:
      case 1:
      case 2:
      ...
      default:
        break;
      }
    }
```

EDIT: in fact I am not sure you need the switch at all, just have a counter for each array and increment when you assign to it.

In the case of the return value of `strtok()` you must take care to allocate memory for the return value in order to store the value between each iteration since it uses a static buffer of the original string when it returns tokens, but if you directly convert the token you don't need to.

When you check the value of the character use one of the standard c runtime
functions for that purpose isdigit() isalpha()/islower() instead of checking ASCII 
value directly.